# run second ksh script after first ksh is done

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I have 3 scripts for example: first.ksh, second.ksh, third.ksh.

I run all of those scripts one by one manually, when the first is done I run the second and then also the third. those scripts take time to run, doing them manually is time-consuming because is required me to be in front of the computer.

how can write a script or query which runs those scripts one by one, after one is finished, automatically?

Comment: Put the 3 invocation in  a single script, and run this master script.

Comment: Alternatively, define a function for this in ksh startup file.

Comment: _how can write a script or query_  : What do you mean by _query_?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the scripts are in the current working directory,

```bash
./first.sh ; ./second.sh ; ./third.sh
```

Where `;` is the separator for "sequential list"

The topic you're looking for is "shell programming". There are many Unix shells, and they share basic features defined by POSIX and Single Unix Specification. Most of them have additional features as well as online documentations.

Comment: There's the `date` command which tells the time. If you want to know when the scripts started (and finished), I'll add an example for it. It's too verbose to be a one-liner.